# foreach first list and see if it exists in the 2nd list and if it does then get other values from 2nd list

Tags: c#

foreach  first list by using `ID` and `ID_SCH` and see if it exists in the 2nd list and if it does then get other values from 2nd list.

```
string getRecords = "SELECT .....";
         List <Records> firstList = ReadAll(getRecords, reader => {
           return new Records(
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.ID, string.Empty),
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.ID_SCH, string.Empty)
           );
         });

         string getAllRecords = "SELECT .....";

         List <Records> secondList = ReadAll(getAllRecords, reader => {
           return new Records(
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.ID, string.Empty),
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.ID_SCH, string.Empty),
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.BSID, string.Empty),
             reader.ReadByName(NameRecord.BSID_SCH, string.Empty),
           );
         });

// currently I am able to use id only. But I would like to include `id` and `id_sch` as well in the below statement and then get the value of `BSID` and `BSID_SCH`.

var aa= data.Select(l1 => l1.Id).Intersect(secondList .Select(l2 => l2.Id)).ToList();
```

Acceptance criteria

1.foreach test in the first list see if it exists in the 2nd list. `some how I managed to use` id`to get the result but I would like to use`id_sch` as well.

2. if it does, get the tests that are excluded from 2nd list like BSID and BSID_SCH
3. after getting the `BSID` and `BSID_SCH` value from acceptance criteria 2, need to check if these `BSID` and `BSID_SCH` value exist in `firstlist`
4. If it exists in the first list then how to get the value of `id idsch` from first list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples to combine the two values. In a first step we add the values of the first list into a `HashSet<T>`, so that we can test whether an item exists fast and easily.

```cs
var l1Exclude = data
    .Select(l1 => (l1.Id, l1.id_sch))
    .ToHashSet();
var l1Include = data
    .Select(l1 => (l1.BSID, l1.BSID_SCH))
    .ToHashSet();
```

Now, you can use this result to filter the second list with of all its properties

```cs
IEnumerable<Records> result = secondList
    .Where(l2 => l1Include.Contains((l2.BSID, l2.BSID_SCH)) &&
                 !l1Exclude.Contains((l2.Id, l2.id_sch)));
```

---

But a fundamental question is, whether it would not be easier and faster to perform this logic in SQL directly yielding the expected result. Something like this

```sql
SELECT b.*
FROM
    Table2 b
    INNER JOIN Table1 a
        ON b.BSID = a.BSID AND b.BSID_SCH = a.BSID_SCH
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM Table1 aa
                WHERE aa.Id = b.Id AND aa.IdSch = b.IdSch)
```

Comment: This gives me the value of `id` and `id_sch`. But I would to add one more condition where I can get the value of `BSID` and `BSID_SCH` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting the value of `BSID` and `BSID_SCH`. Could you also please provide my 3rd acceptance criteria. How do I check if this `BSID` and `BSID_sch` value exist in `firstlist`. I am trying like this `var values = firstlist.Where(x => result.Contains(x.BSID,x.BSID_sch));` but it is throwing compile time error.

Comment: You're missing a `(` required to make a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples): `var values = firstlist.Where(x => result.Contains( (x.BSID,x.BSID_sch) );`. But this works only if `firstList` actually is a list of tuples and this is very slow for lists. So, only apply the `Contains` test on a `HashSet`.